# How to create Silverlight 4 user control for windows phone app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can I create a silverlight user control that will work on a windows phone silverlight?

Is there a way to do so? I don't need very complex things. just a very simple user control with a label and a few text boxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and yes. Here is a [link for starters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). If you scroll to the bottom you will see supported version info. And yes, user controls are supported for Silverlight for Windows Phone v 7.0

Just above the version info is also a clear, straightforward example of the simple kind of user control that you're interested in creating.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can as long as Controls you are using in Custom Control are also supported in Silverlight for WP7. in MSDN doc there is description of which Version of Silverlight supports it with weather its available in WP7. Also in doc every Method, Property ,Event ,etc  has an [image]icon in front of it. which will tell if its available in WP7 or not.

Comment: Just as a question on this - are you better targetting Silverlight3 for the shared control instead of Silverlight4?